# Changing 'rewrite' argument after custom post type is registered

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm am attempting to change the rewrite argument after it has been defined and passed as an argument for 'register_post_type' in a plugin. My issue is that I am utilizing a plugin that defines a custom post type. I can manually edit the rewrite argument in the plugin; however, doing so will mean that I have to do this every time the plugin updates. I was wondering if there is a way that I can change this with some code in another plugin or functions.php file.

I was thinking there might be a function that would allow me to alter these arguments or a way in which I could unregister and reregister the custom post type.

Any ideas?

Comment: See "solution" answer why I choose to close vote that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar question and found the answer. Take a look, it might be helpful for You aswell: [Change custom post type to hierarchical after being registered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/solved-change-custom-post-type-to-hierarchical-after-being-registered)

Answer (score 0):

Which plugin are you using? If you are using custom post UI this is possible. I can point to the right direction once I know which plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using WP E-Commerce. I want to change the rewrite rule without touching the plugin.

Comment: May be the solution is defining new taxonomies for the custom post type defined by WP E-Commerce.